# Java SpringBoot Postgres remove rows

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbc

Help me please to remove the row in Postgres by clicking the **Del** button.
Maybe to link id in DB and id on the HTML page, but how?
Maybe I need to parse the HTML page and pass String id?
Any ideas will help me.

here is my database schema:

[image]

```
<table class="tmc">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th><th>TMC</th><th>SN</th><th>Owner</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#messages}}
<tr>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td><span>{{text}}</span></td>
    <td><i>{{sn}}</i></td>
    <td><i>{{owner}}</i></td>
    <th><form action="/remove" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Del"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
    </form>
    </th>
</tr>
{{/messages}}
</tbody>
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String text;
private String sn;
private String owner;

public Message() {
}

public Message(String text, String sn, String owner) {
    this.text = text;
    this.sn = sn;
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

Rows are forming in database by:

```
@PostMapping("/main")
public String add (
        @RequestParam String owner,
        @RequestParam String text,
        @RequestParam String sn, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Message message = new Message (text, sn, owner);
    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty() & sn != null && !sn.isEmpty() & owner != null && 
!owner.isEmpty()) {
        if (!text.matches("^[0-9].*$")) {
            messageRepo2.save(message);
            Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo2.findAll();
            model.put("messages", messages);
        } else
            model.put("error", "ТМЦ не должно начинаться с цифры");
        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo2.findAll();
        model.put("messages", messages);
    } else {
        model.put("error", "Заполните все поля!");
        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo2.findAll();
        model.put("messages", messages);
    }
    return "main";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your html code:

1. it would be to let the `form` element outside the `table`
2. need to use `<input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="{{xxx}}" />` in order to let it can pass parameter to your controller method

```html
<form action="/remove" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
    <table class="tmc">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>TMC</th><th>SN</th><th>Owner</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#messages}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{id}} <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{id}}" /></td>
        <td><span>{{text}}</span></td>
        <td><i>{{sn}}</i>   <input type="hidden" name="sn" value="{{sn}}" /></td>
        <td><i>{{owner}}</i> <input type="hidden" name="owner" value="{{owner}}" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Del"/></td>
        </th>
    </tr>
    {{/messages}}
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This helped me find the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID ТМЦ</th><th>Наименование ТМЦ</th><th>Серийный номер ТМЦ</th><th>За кем числится</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#messages}}
<tr>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td><span>{{text}}</span></td>
    <td><i>{{sn}}</i></td>
    <td><i>{{owner}}</i></td>
    <td>
    <form action="/remove" method="post" name="remove">
        <input type="submit" value="Удалить"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="sn" value="{{sn}}"/>
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>
{{/messages}}
</tbody>
```

```
import com.example.webapp.domain.Message;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
@Transactional
   public interface MessageDel extends CrudRepository<Message, Long>{
   List<Message> deleteBySn (String sn);
}

@PostMapping("/remove")
public String remove (@RequestParam String sn, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Message messagedel = new Message (sn);
    messageDel.deleteBySn(sn);
    model.put("messages", messagedel);
    return "redirect:/main";
}
```